# How many trips can you do on a B2 visa in a year?

Tags: visas, usa, repeat-visits

On a B2 visa, can you stay for only 6 months in one year or it is just that you cannot stay for more than 6 months in one trip?

So for example you can stay for say 4 months and then go back to your home country for 4 months and then come back to the US for 4 months. So practically you stayed for 8 months in one year.